# Break out of loop from included file?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am trying to organize my "actions" a little bit better, currently it is a giant switch statement with a ton of cases, and it's very hard to manage. I want to move the actions into their own files that can be managed easier. But I am trying to sort through an issue.

I have a foreach loop that loops over all the "called actions" and calls them. Then I have a bunch of actions, but some actions I want to end execution of the current loop (i.e. `continue;` or `break;`) but that does not seem to be working on an included file.

Is there anyway else I could do this? I also need the "actions" to have access to all the current variables defined in the executing script (which is why I went for include).

Currently...

included_file.php

```
<?php
blah blah stuff
if(statement) {
   // accesses variables declared in calling_file.php
   continue;
}
?>
```

calling_file.php

```
<?php
blah blah stuff
// declare variables that need to be accessed in included_files.php
foreach() {
include included_file.php
}
?>
```

Now for some actions I want to stop the current loop and move onto the next. Any ideas?

Comment: Break within the included file. Do you really want to include the file for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: No not really... but functions don't seem any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, it appears you want to get a result from the included file that signals what you want to do (`break`,`continue`) and then a simple switch statement to allow an inner loop to `break` an outer loop. The [break control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) will allow you to do this.

**calling_file.php**

```
<?php

$includes = array ('included_file1.php', 'included_file2.php', 'included_file3.php');

const CONTROL_BREAK = 3;
const CONTROL_CONTINUE = 7;

// declare variables that need to be accessed in included_files.php
foreach($includes as $include) {
    print "Including $include\n";
    $result = include($include);
    switch ($result){
        case CONTROL_BREAK:
            break 2;

        case CONTROL_CONTINUE:

        default:
            continue 2;
    }
}
```

**included_file1.php**

```
<?php
print __FILE__ . " has been included!\n";

if(TRUE) {
   print "I should continue!\n";
   return CONTROL_CONTINUE;
}
```

**included_file2.php**

```
<?php
print __FILE__ . " has been included!\n";

if(TRUE) {
   print "I should break!\n";
   return CONTROL_BREAK;
}
```

**included_file3.php**

```
<?php
print __FILE__ . " has been included!\n";

if(TRUE) {
   print "You should never see me!";
}
```